# Are derivatives of the solution to parabolic PDEs dominated by gaussian densities?

Tags: differential-equations, parabolic-pde

Consider the parabolic PDE for $p:\mathbb R_+^2\to\mathbb R_+$

$$\partial_tp =a(t,x)\partial^2_{xx}p+b(t,x)\partial_x b+c(t,x)p,\quad \forall t,x>0 \quad (\ast)$$

and $p(0,\cdot)=p_0$ and $p(\cdot,0)=0$, where $a,b,c:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ are  Lipschitz/bounded s.t. $\inf_{(t,x)}a(t,x)>0$ and $p_0:\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R_+$ is a probability density function. For any $\delta>0$, define $\phi_{\delta}:(0,\infty)\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R_+$ by

$$\phi_{\delta}(t,x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\delta\pi t}}e^{-x^2/2\delta t}.$$

Do there exist $K,\delta>0$ (depending on $a,b,c,p_0$) s.t.

$$|\partial_x p(t,x) |\le \frac{K}{\sqrt{t}}\phi_{\delta}(t,x)\quad \mbox{and}\quad |\partial^2_{xx} p(t,x) |\le \frac{K}{t}\phi_{\delta}(t,x)$$

hold for all $t,x>0$?

Any answer, comments and references are highly appreciated.

PS : In many books on the regularity of the solution, the estimation of the uniform norm $\|\partial_{x} p\|_{\infty},\|\partial^2_{xx} p\|_{\infty}$ is given, while no result on the above comparison is found. The only comparison result that I find is for the equation $(\ast)$ with the initial condition (no boundary condition), and I wish to know whether it still holds for my case.